# Is there a way to increase the amount of characters allowed in an UPDATE statement?

Tags: ms-access, vba

After searching in the internet, I found many places that say the max is 2048 characters. The trouble is all the strings I have been handed to update are 2500+

If there isn't a way of doing it in ms access, is there a database system that will let me do it?

Comment: unclear. Do you speak about the size of the SQL Statement ? the size of the text fields ? or...?

Comment: *Each `string`* is 2500+ characters? As in 1 field?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using string concatenation (also known as "dynamic SQL") to build an UPDATE statement and you are running into a limitation on the number of characters that the resulting SQL string can contain then you have a couple of options:

1. You could use a *parameterized query* to perform the update. The SQL command itself will be much shorter because it doesn't include the actual string values that you are writing to the database. Those values are passed to the query (which is either a `DAO.QueryDef` object or an `ADODB.Command` object) as separate *parameters* that don't (directly) affect the length of the SQL command.
2. You could also use a *Recordset update* to apply the new string values. (That is: open a Recordset object, update a record, and then save the changes.)

A simple web search should provide you with plenty of examples for each technique.